# Is it possible to declare a global variable in php that assigned from a function

Tags: php

Is is possible to fill a variable like this:

I have a class on php like this :

```
class Cek_list_wire_rod extends Members_Controller {
    private $table_generate;

public function ajax_list() {
    $record_num = $this->uri->segment($this->uri->total_segments());
    $list = $this->cek_list->get_datatables($record_num);
    $this->table_generate = $list;   // Create an array object

/*.....*/
}

public function generate_pdf_laporan() {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r ($this->table_generate); //Empty 
}
```

For the help, it so appreciated

Comment: What variable do you think is global?

Comment: How are you instantiating the class and calling its methods?

Comment: Well the answer is yes. But I dont see what relevance this code is to the question

Comment: I mean, $this->table_generate after assigned from another function will be handling a value, so $this->table_generate have a value if I will be use on another function,

Answer (score 1):

It should work just fine as shown [here](http://codepad.org/CeKWMNkl).

```
<?php class Cek_list_wire_rod {
    private $table_generate;

public function ajax_list() {
    //$record_num = $this->uri->segment($this->uri->total_segments());
    //$list = $this->cek_list->get_datatables($record_num);// not needed in demo
    $this->table_generate = '555';   // populating the test data

/*.....*/
}

public function generate_pdf_laporan() {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r ($this->table_generate); //Empty 
}
}

$test = new Cek_list_wire_rod();
$test->ajax_list(); // calling this method since the value is being populated in this method.
$test->generate_pdf_laporan();
```

Furthermore, this is just using the class attribute to store the data and not using global variables.

As evedient from the code, you need to first call the `ajax_list()` method then call the `generate_pdf_laporan()` method, since the attribute and its vallue is being set in the former.